# SQLPLUS single row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: subquery, sqlplus

I have this query inside a cursor in SQLPLUS

```
SELECT last_name, department_id, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary >(SELECT AVG(salary)
               FROM employees
               GROUP BY department_id)
ORDER BY department_id;
```

And it's giving the error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I know that the error is in line 3, but I just don't know how to fix it, if someone could help me, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have multiple departments in your employees table. So your sub query returns average salary for each department.

You can try the below query;

```
    SELECT last_name, department_id, salary
    FROM employees e1
    WHERE salary >(SELECT AVG(salary)
               FROM employees e2
               WHERE e2.department_id = e1.department_id
               GROUP BY e2.department_id)
    ORDER BY department_id;
```

However this method will cause the sub-query to calculate the average salaries to run for each row.

Better approach can be;

```
    SELECT e1.last_name, e1.department_id, e1.salary
    FROM employees e1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT department_id, AVG(salary) avgsalary
               FROM employees
               GROUP BY department_id) as AvgSalaries on e1.department_id = AvgSalaries.department_Id
    WHERE e1.salary > AvgSalaries.avgsalary
    ORDER BY department_id;
```

This way average salaries are calculated only once for all departments.

Just noticed this is for oracle, syntax might be slightly different but general idea should be the same.